# Chart on WCF service

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, charts

i want generate a chart in a wcf servi but visual studio express 2013 don't recognize

```
System.Web.DataVisualization
```

in my cs class... I have the following chart

```
private static void grafico()
{

    var list = VelocidadeList.OrderByDescending(c => c.Veloc).ToList();

    foreach (Velocidade rel in list)
    {
        string[] x = new string[4] { "vei2", "vei3", "vei4", "vei5" };
        int[] y = new int[4] { 200, 112, 55, 96 };
    }
    Chart chart1 = new Chart();
}
```

dont recognize the Chart control.

My question is if its possible generate a chart without a asp page?

thanks

Comment: I would consider a chart to be a UI-specific item.  In that case, the WCF service should return the **data** necessary for the chart, but how the client displays the data should be left to the client.

Comment: i'm generating reports on wcf and would be awesome if i can generate and send in email. thanks.